# Как в с++ в linux перегрузить ввод/вывод в сокеты?

Tags: linux, классы, c++, сокет

Необходимо перегрузить ввод/вывод через сокеты как stream в с++. Или, если можете подскажите библеотеку, которая это реализует с примерами использования. Библеотеку на подобии этой
http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/lavender/courses/socket++/
Но эта библиотека не работает (похоже сильно устарела и некоторые функции неизвестно что делают и откуда взялись, которые не работают)

Comment: Посмотрите `man fdopen`. 

     FILE *in = fdopen(sock, "r");
     FILE *out = fdopen(dup(sock),"w");

Собственно, сокет это двунаправленный канал обмена, и `dup()` нужен если Вы собираетесь закрывать одно из направлений и использовать только второе. 

Например для HTTP POST, если Content-Length неизвестна и конец запроса определяется закрытием клиентом передающего потока.

--

Конечно, это потоки C, а не C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

библиотеку можно и поковырять, но может воспользоваться другими, у которых это работает? например Poco - [Poco::Net::socket](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf).

Еще есть классическое решение - буст - [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете перегрузить функцию socket(), которая вернет вам объект вашего класса, а потом для этого класса реализуете оператор >> и <<, в них подаёте строковые переменные или какие другие (в случае со строковыми передавайте строку, завершающуюся нуль байтом, или если надо передавать не аски символы, то наваяйте структуру с размером и строкой) типы, и для каждого надо свою перегруженную версию >>. Поскольку при отправке в сокет обычно нужен только сам сокет, данные, их размер и флаг, то в классе вам хватит переменной int, которая и является сокетом и ваши две перегруженные функции. Кстати, как правило обработка ответов ведется после отправки|принятия (send, recv) и от этого как правило часто зависят результаты сетевого взаимодействия, так что советую либо воздержаться от этой реализации, либо встроить в класс функцию наподобие GetLastError(), которая будет вам возвращать результаты работы функций recv и send, в перегруженных операторах. Но если честно это уже попахивает идиотизмом и запутанностью кода. Удачи :)